# Laravel - How to Dynamically implement my API

Tags: laravel

I am consuming an external API using Guzzle and saving it into database:

```
use App\Employee;

public function handle()
{  
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $res = $client->request('GET','https://api.employees.net/allemployees');
    $clientdatas = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);

   foreach($clientdatas as $clientdata)
    {
        $employee = HrEmployee::updateOrCreate([
            'employee_code' => $clientdata['staff_id'],
        ],
        [
            'first_name'                            => $clientdata['first_name'],
            'last_name'                             => $clientdata['last_name'],
            'other_name'                            => $clientdata['middle_name'],
            'dept_code'                            => $clientdata['department_id']
        ]);  
     }
  }
```

Currently what I have is that if

'employee_code' => $clientdata['staff_id'],

exists, it should update

```
        [
            'first_name'                            => $clientdata['first_name'],
            'last_name'                             => $clientdata['last_name'],
            'other_name'                            => $clientdata['middle_name'],
            'dept_code'                            => $clientdata['department_id']
        ]);
```

it should save new records.

However, I want to change it that if

'employee_code' => $clientdata['staff_id'],
exists, it should update

```
        [
            'first_name'                            => $clientdata['first_name'],
            'last_name'                             => $clientdata['last_name'],
            'other_name'                            => $clientdata['middle_name'],
        ]);
```

except

```
        [
           'dept_code'                            => $clientdata['department_id']
        ]);
```

If not, it should save everything

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: It should update or it should save?, I think it's not clear

Comment: @OsDev - What I mean is that, if data already exists (that is if  'employee_code' => $clientdata['staff_id'],) it should not update this:   'dept_code'                            => $clientdata['department_id'].   That means it should exclude it.    But if its a new record it save 'dept_code'                            => $clientdata['department_id']. along with other records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create payloads based on `$clientdata['staff_id']`

```
$payloads = [
   'first_name' => $clientdata['first_name'],
   'last_name' => $clientdata['last_name'],
   'other_name' => $clientdata['middle_name']
];

if(!isset($clientdata['staff_id']) { // only add dept_code if staff_id is not set
   $payloads['dept_code'] = $clientdata['department_id'];
}

$employee = HrEmployee::updateOrCreate([
            'employee_code' => $clientdata['staff_id'],
        ], $payloads);
```

Comment: When I did as you advised, it now underlines this:

> payloads['nav_dept_id'] = $clientdata['department_id']; 

> Syntax error
 unexpected: =
 after: ]

Comment: forgot the `$` before `payloads` variable